# How do I clear specific columns in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

i am using WPF, connected to SQL DataBase via LinqToSql.
I have filled DataGrid using ItemsSource.

I would like to clear everything in my DataGrid, except first two rows(ID,first and second name), and Headers ofcourse, by pressing a button. All items i would like to(either set to null or 0) remove, are floats, but I can't find the right logic to do that.

Here is the picture of my DataGrid-->[image]

```
public partial class Spisak : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window
{
    DiplomskiDataContext diplomski = new DiplomskiDataContext();
    public Spisak()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridRadnici.ItemsSource = diplomski.Radniks.ToList();
    }
}
```

This is my code behind, and here is Xaml code:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGridRadnici" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="260" Margin="10,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ime" Binding="{Binding Ime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prezime" Binding="{Binding Prezime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="BrSati" Binding="{Binding BrojSati, Converter={StaticResource ThreePlaceConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prekovremeni" Binding="{Binding BrojPrekovremenih, Converter={StaticResource ThreePlaceConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gorivo" Binding="{Binding BrojDana, Converter={StaticResource ThreePlaceConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bonus" Binding="{Binding Bonus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VracanjeDuga" Binding="{Binding VracanjeDuga}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="UkZarada" Binding="{Binding UkupnaPlata, Converter={StaticResource ThreePlaceConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="UkSaGorivom" Binding="{Binding UkupnoSaGorivom, Converter={StaticResource ThreePlaceConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Izmeni" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Obrisi" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Clear the property values of the entity object.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Unfortunately not unless you give you some more information about how you populate the `DataGrid`. Please update your question with the relevant code snippets.

Comment: I have done just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the columns that you want to be able to blank out from `float` to `Nullable<float>` (`float?`) and simply set the properties to `null`:

```
var sourceList = dataGridRadnici.ItemsSource as List<Radnik>; //or whatever your data is called
foreach (var item in sourceList)
{
    item.BrojPrekovremenih = null; // or 0
    //set the other properties the same way...
}
```

You also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise [property change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) in your data class.

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me, but there was no need to do anything with the float values because it has "allow null" values in SQL database. Thank you very much.

Comment: I maybe didn't ask the question in correct way.
This is working, but I need to clear those values in SQL base aswell. This code clears them in DataGrid, but not in the base.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It works just fine if you SubmitChanges in the end. Thanks again!